# Save/Backup Data Feeds in dynamic folders (date) under a dynamic name (date)

Tags: api, date, key, directory

this is the script

```
@echo off
set curr_date=%date:~-4,4%\%date:~-10,2%
mkdir "C:\Users\%curr_date%"
SET "FILENAME=C:\Users\%curr_date%\XML-ALL_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%.xml"
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" "http://a-website.com/b2b_feed.php?key={api-key}&sort=xml&type=xml&lang=en&version=2015" "%FILENAME%"
```

I having trouble with bitsadmin.exe. It doesn't get the XML file. Can someone help? Thx